# Do you get opportunity attacks on creatures that are pushed?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reactions

A Tempest Cleric gets the ability to push a creature 10ft away when casting lightning damage on them. If a spell that pushes a target away while they are in close quarters with one of my allies, does the ally get to make an opportunity attack on the creature as it is pushed away?

Comment: @Szega That question is related but I don't actually think that this straight up question has actually been asked.

Comment: @DaleM The answer is exactly the same though. And I do not think the situations are meaningfully different.

Comment: I guess it's called an "opportunity attack", not a "reaction shot". Calling it a "shot" is confusing, since you can't actually shoot as a opportunity attack. Did you mean the Ready action, when a player announces something like "I shoot him when it moves"?

Comment: @enkryptor I would not allow the shot if the ready action trigger was that. "when it moves" implies using its own movement, moving on its own volition. I'd allow if the trigger was "I shoot him if he leaves the space he is in now".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

> You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.

PHB, 195

Comment: So turned undead (because they flee using the reactioin) do provoke a AoO?